# Non finite clauses

Tags: verbs, clauses, present-progressive, nonfinite-verbs

I wonder if you guys can help me?

I'm really struggling to identify non-finite clauses as the online definitions (infinitives and -ing forms) don't seem adequate to explain them.

For example, in the clause complex:

Scientists are now capable of creating new types of crop || by taking genetic material from one, or more, existing plants, || and engineering them into the genes of another species.||

Is it only the first clause that is finite (as the others are all in the -ing form)?

If not can you please explain why?

Thanks for your helps,

RV

Comment: The _creating_, _taking_ and _engineering_ clauses are all gerund-participial non-finite clauses. The _creating_ clause is complement of the preposition "of" and the other two are coordinated complements of the preposition "by". The verb in the matrix clause is the finite copula "be", which has the entire sequence starting with "now capable" as one large adjectival phrase as predicative complement of "be" in its ascriptive sense

Comment: @Araucaria Yeah, I must stop doing that! (Btw, I made a small correction to my comment, hence the replacement.

Comment: Thanks @BillJ for showing me how much you know but I could do with an answer which sheds a little more light thanks.

Comment: @user152022 I'm not sure what more I can add, but I've posted an answer which I hope answers your concerns.

Answer (score 1):

The only finite clause is the matrix one (the entire sentence), with the finite "be" as its verb. The subordinate clauses - there are three of them - are all non-finite gerund-participials, sometimes called *ing* clauses:

1. Creating new types of crop.
2. Taking genetic material from one or more existing plants.
3. Engineering them into the genes of another plant.

Comment: That's the spirit @BillJ!  Thank you, this helps a lot.